# What is the best / easiest way to talk to SQLite from .NET?

Tags: .net, sqlite

Question says it all, really. 
My application is a time tracker.  It's currently written as a spreadsheet, but there's just too much data and I would like to impose a bit more structure on it.

[SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) seems like a neat way to go.
I would be open to other suggestions, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some providers available:

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2

And you can get up and running in just three minutes according to this chap:

http://www.mikeduncan.com/sqlite-on-dotnet-in-3-mins/

**Updated Jan 5 2009:** We actually have this rolled out to our shared (partial trust) hosting environment and it works really well according to early customer feedback.

Comment: Thanks.  the 3 minute article is pure gold.  I'm up and running now!

Answer (score 1):

The current (april 2011) links seem to be [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) System.Data.SQLite 1.0.70.0 (3.7.6)

But there seems to be some problem with the installer. The doen't install SQLite.Interop.dll properly to GAC.

I did not install it in GAC and load it with absolut path and that works fine for me.

Just noted, that the [ticket](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=54e52d4c6f) is open again. Check there for new work arounds and solutions.

Comment: Note that SQLite.Interop.dll is unmanaged code and therefore doesn't belong in the GAC at all. Doesn't mean it's not a pain though - took me about a day to get something working and I'm still not sure which Voodoo trick was the one that worked...

Comment: @Mike Woodhouse Just trying to do it with W7 64 bit. Don't know how to. But I got it to work within a W7-32 VM. I'm not really amused.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on an open source application and want a lightweight interop layer to SQLite, then the SQLite code in Media Portal may be of interest (see SQLiteClient.cs)